# portforwarding setup nginx to self-signed certificate

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, portforwarding, self-signed-certificate

I have a bastion server that can allow me to connect to one private web server, this means I have set up double tunnel ssh where I allow to connect to my application in localhost:3000, so when I use this in my browser looks like localhost:8081 to connect to my private web server

`ssh -L 8081:ip-x-x-x-x.ec2.internal:3000 -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-X-X-X-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

```
       DIAGRAM
```

http://localhost:8081 => bastion(EC2) => (nodejs running in port 3000, nginx Aplication)

I need certificate my API with my own Self-Signed Certificate

My application running on nodejs with pm2.
I already try to use Nginx to apply my self-signed certificate on my API in the web server, But I don't know what missed, because when try to use mysite.com nothing happens

```
server{
    listen 443;
    server  mysite.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}
```